# Excel, Increasing Time Series find the average time between adjacent points

Tags: excel

I have a list as follows

```
17:25:25
17:27:55
17:30:40
17:40:04
17:42:40
17:45:20
17:48:00
17:50:20
17:52:53
17:57:03
18:02:45
18:07:00
18:09:00
18:10:10
```

I wish to find the average distance between adjacent points, is there a function within excel that does this. Currently, I have a second column that works out the distance between the points such as

```
17:25:25    00:02:30    Average:    00:03:22
17:27:55    00:02:45
17:30:40    00:09:24
17:40:04    00:02:36
17:42:40    00:02:40
17:45:20    00:02:40
17:48:00    00:02:20
17:50:20    00:02:33
17:52:53    00:04:10
17:57:03    00:05:42
18:02:45    00:04:15
18:07:00    00:02:00
18:09:00    00:01:10
18:10:10
```

And then at the bottom i average all of the second column, this is not great as i keep having to edit the AVERAGE(K1:Kx) in the cell as i add more times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(AVERAGE(J2:INDEX(J:J,MATCH(1E+99,J:J))-J1:INDEX(J:J,MATCH(1E+99,J:J)-1)))
```

No need for a helper column and this formula is dynamic, in that it will Increase or decrease based on the numbers in column J.

[image]

Comment: Is this limited to just time or can this be used for dates as well?

Comment: Time and dates to excel are just numbers, so yes it will.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formula here.

If you're not familiar with array formulas, the significant difference is you enter the formula into the cell then press and hold Ctrl + Shift then hit Enter instead of just hitting Enter.

If you've done that, you'll notice the formula starts and ends with curly brackets instead of just the equal sign at the beginning. Do not type the curly brackets. That won't do any good.

Assuming the sheet name is "Sheet1" and your data is in column A starting at row 1, enter the following formula in the cell where you want the average.

```
{=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A2:A"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX((Sheet1!$A:$A<>"")*ROW(Sheet1!$A:$A))))-INDIRECT("A1:A"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX((Sheet1!$A:$A<>"")*ROW(Sheet1!$A:$A)))-1))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is how I would do this except I would change your average formula to:

```
=Average(K:K)
```

That way it'll include values as you add them (assuming that K will only have the differences). Then you can hide the K column so that you don't see the differences if you do not want to.

Comment: Yes in the end i used, =(MAX(D:D)-MIN(D:D))/COUNTA(D:D)

Comment: @ed-wright that gives a different answer than the average of the change as you are including one too many numbers in your average: for the average of the changes you want  the denominator to = `(COUNT(D:D) -1)`  You should also post that as an answer for futures visitors.